# Summing along an entire array in Fortran 90

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have an array that is of size [30,3500,7000], and would like to accumulate along the first dimension so I am left with a [3500,7000] array. I have tried the following:

```
Implicit None
REAL,INTENT(IN) :: datastored(30,3500,7000),emptyarray(3500,7000)
REAL,INTENT(OUT) :: summed(3500,7000)

INTEGER :: i, j, r

DO i = 1,3500
  DO j = 1,7000
    DO r = 1,30
      summed(i,j) = emptyarray(i,j) + datastored(r,i,j)
```

The problem with this is that, for some reason, it will not sum along the r dimension, and the summed variable will only be the last 'r' value in datastored, basically mirroring datastored(30,i,j).

Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't define either `emptyarray` or `datastored`: please provide a real example (see [mre]). Note, too, that the values in `summed` don't depend on values across iterations of `r`: please explain what you think the code is doing.  Also, why don't you consider using the `sum` intrinsic which appears suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
summed = sum(datastored, DIM = 1)
```

Check [this version](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf) of the Fortran standard, item 13.7.161, which defines the instrinsic `sum`. The Example case *(iii)* is **exactly** what you are asking for.